# Pimcore Which event is fired when first time product save?

Tags: events, pimcore

**Pimcore** How to get event for first time product save using backend.

I have to apply some logic for first time product creation in pimcore.

How to find event name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the event is 'object.preAdd'.

If the Id of the saved object is 0, it's a newly created one

```
\Pimcore::getEventManager()->attach("object.preAdd", function (\Zend_EventManager_Event $e) {
    // your code goes here
});
```

It would probably be best if you stick the code above into a custom made plugin to ensure it's executed on every call.

See https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Event_API_and_Event_Manager.html for more information

Comment: "The most common use-case for events is using them in a plugin, but of course you can use them also anywhere in your code or when hooking into the startup process."
That means: Add them in startup.php